# (Google App Script) Can i give access to other users to my private Spreadsheet with oAuth?

Tags: authentication, google-apps-script, oauth-2.0, authorization, google-sheets

i need help for my application "Google App Script".

I am the owner of a Spreadsheet that I use as a DB in my application; this spreadsheet must remain private.

My application is executed as Gadget in Google Site, in this application a user runs the script as himself (not under the owner's identity).

I need that all users who access the application can get some data from the DB Spreadsheet.

How can users get this data, if the Spreadsheet is only accessible to me?

Can I use oAuth?

Sorry for the bad English

Answer (score 1):

Following Zig answer and to illustrate, here is an example of such a contentService webapp, one can call it with this url either in a browser or in urlFetch

The app is deployed as follows : *execute as me* and *anyone can access even anonymous*

[image]
https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxfk5YR-JIlhv7HG9R7F-cPxmL0NZRzrdGF4VFGxGivBkYeZY4/exec?&user=chris&row=4&sheet=Sheet1

and here is the demo script

```
function doGet(e) {
  if(e.parameter.user!='serge' && e.parameter.user!='chris' ){return ContentService.createTextOutput("logging error, you are not allowed to see this").setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT)};
  var sheet = e.parameter.sheet;
  var row = Number(e.parameter.row);
  Logger.log(sheet+'  '+row);
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("0AnqSFd3iikE3dENnemR2LVFMTFM5bDczNGhfSG11LVE");// this sheet is private but anyone can call this app
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName(sheet);
  var range = sh.getRange(row,1,1,sh.getLastColumn());
  var val = Utilities.jsonStringify(range.getValues());
  var result = ContentService.createTextOutput(val).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  return result;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No you cant use oauth from the gadget as the user doesnt have read permission.
However you can publish a second script to extract needed data that runs as you with anonymous public access and call that one with urlfetch from the 1st. Slower thou.